# One way back up on Google Drive?

Tags: windows-7, onedrive, google-drive, online-backup, online-storage

Is it possible to automatically upload whatever is in a particular folder on my computer to google drive but not download what is on google drive and missing on my computer? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not automatically perform a one-way sync using Google Drive.

- Make sure you have Google Drive uninstall as an application
- Go the folder or files you are interested in uploading
- Bring up drive.google.com on Chrome
- Drag the folder or set of files to Google Drive web page
- Leave web page open
- It will start uploading the folder or files to Google Drive